# Got a error that I do not understand when adding 2 array string converted to int together

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is the error I have found: FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
System.Number.StringToNumber (System.String str, System.Globalization.NumberStyles options, System.Number+NumberBuffer& number, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo info, System.Boolean parseDecimal) (at <437ba245d8404784b9fbab9b439ac908>:0)

Edit: argument is 5 4, long backstory, but the split is to turn 5 5 into wordX = 5, wordY = 4, then add it together.

```
string[] numbers = argument.Split(new[] { " " }, System.StringSplitOptions.None);

string wordX = numbers[0];
string wordY = numbers[1];

int numberX = Int32.Parse(wordX);
int numberY = Int32.Parse(wordY);

Debug.Log(numberX + numberY);
```

Comment: Error is quite selexplanatory I'ld say. It comes from `int numberX = Int32.Parse(wordX);
int numberY = Int32.Parse(wordY);` and says the given string value has an incorrect format for parsing it to an `int` .. could you show us the values of `wordX` and `wordY` or simply of `argument`? (`Debug.Log(argument);`)

Answer (score 0):

The code it's working for me .

First of all we are assuming that argument may be a string like this "123 456 789"

Then you could write:

```
string[] numbers = argument.Split();
```

Finally you only have to be sure that numbers(that is a string[] type) contains only strings that can be converted into int variables.
This can be done in many ways , like Int.Tryparse or a simple try-catch block (and see what row gives you the exception)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the string value for your `wordX` and `wordY` are not parse-able to int. I would recommend you to use the TryParse instead to avoid the Exception.

```
if(int.TryParse(wordX, out int numberX) &&
   int.TryParse(wordY, out int numberY))
{
   Debug.Log(numberX + numberY);
}
else
{
   // this will let you see why it was failing
   Debug.Log($"Error Parsing: wordX is [{wordX ?? "null"}] and wordY is [{wordY ?? "null"}]");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
using System;


string data = "1 2 3 4";
string[] s = data.Split(' ');
int num_X = Convert.ToInt32(s[0]);
int num_Y = Convert.ToInt32(s[1]);
Debug.Log(num_X + num_Y);
```